# How to cancel a running job (something went wrong)?

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I have a scheduled job that runs every morning, apparently since yesterday something is not going as planned in the job. And it is still running

The job from yesterday is still running (normally it takes about 14 minutes) And the scheduled job from today started too. But this is also running to long

I do not have an option anywhere (i can find) that gives me the option to cancel the running jobs.....

Any one have an idea where I can cancel these jobs?

Comment: did the answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel the job by doing the following:

- First, go to the job result page (click on the id of the job in cloud dataprep).
- Then, you should see a button in top right corner to view the dataflow job.
  [image: View dataflow job button]
- Click on it.
- In the dataflow UI, there is a button to stop the job.

[image: stop button - dataflow UI]

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing could possibly not be resolved via the normal procedure as 'Hugues' described.

There is a bug in dataprep since 20 june causing dataprep jobs to remain in the status 'in progress' while they are actually finished in dataflow.

Hopefully google will solve the issue soon!